# How to get an Object due to maximum result of a method in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I want to rewrite the below for-loop-statement by lambda expression of java8.

```
public class Test {

    List<ObjectTest> lst;

    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

     int max = 0;
     ObjectTest suitableObj = null;
     for(ObjectTest obj:lst) {
        int result = operation(obj.getA(), obj.getB());
        if(result > max) {
            suitableObj = obj;
            max = result;
        }
     }
}
```

How is it possible by lambda expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `Stream` your `ObjectTest` elements, map them to an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and call the `max()` method to compute the maximum value:

```
int max = lst.stream()
             .mapToInt(obj->operation(obj.getA(), obj.getB()))
             .max()
             .orElse(0); // default value in case the input List is empty
```

EDIT: If you want, after your edit, to find the `ObjectTest` instance having the max value of `operation(obj.getA(), obj.getB())`, you can use `Stream`'s `max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`:

```
ObjectTest max = lst.stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(obj->operation(obj.getA(), obj.getB())))
                    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Adding some newlines/whitespace might make this easier to read. +1

Comment: Pedantically, this doesn't do the same thing as OP's code: you'd need to take the max of this with zero, since this code could return a negative result if there is at least one thing in the stream.

Comment: @AndyTurner I can argue that the OP's code probably has a bug (assuming it is expected to support negative numbers).

Comment: @Eran oh, I agree - that's why I prefixed the comment with "pedantically".

Comment: I have edited my question. please refer again and answer.

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin should you also modify `max` in your edited version? (assuming you want to find the instance having the max value)

Comment: @Eran I have edited again. I want to get an ObjectTest  due to the max value.

Comment: @Eran Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

@Eran's answer is the most concise, but you should consider writing an overloaded method:

```
public int operation(ObjectTest o) {
    return o.getA() * o.getB();
}
```

Then you could simply write:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.maxBy;

list.stream().max(comparing(Test::operation)).orElse(null);
```

to obtain the object for which operation yields the maximum result, and

```
list.stream().maToInt(comparing(Test::operation)).max().orElse(0);
```

to obtain the the maximum result.